# How To Handle And Merge Chunked Files From HTML/Javascript in .NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, file-upload, chunks

I have a project where I want to **split files in chunks and merge them on the server side**. On the client side, I create multiple blob files with this snippet:

```js
block = function(_offset, length, _file) {
  var r = new FileReader();
  var blob = _file.slice(_offset, length + _offset);
  chunkNumber = chunkNumber + 1;
  r.onload = foo;
  //r.readAsText(blob);
  //r.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  r.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}
```

**On the server side, I merge the chunks, but the result is not the original file.** 
I tried using "r.readAsBinaryString()",
saved each chunk in one file and merged them. The files are numbered in the order of the POST calls, so it's not a matter of the chunk order.
What I tried when saving the "blob file from the client":

- Converting the string to a byte array and write it to a file (results in a smaller file than the original one)
- Writing the strings directly to a file (results in a bigger file than the original one), but when I open both files in notepad, I see some similarities.

Could anyone please explain what data format the JavaScript API is transmitting to the server and how can I merge these data together to get the original file?
Thanks in advance!